# Apply diff() to pandas multiindex level?

Tags: python, pandas, diff, multi-index, levels

I have a dataframe

```
                   A     B  
Date      Price    
2019-8-1  1000     1.1   0.0
          1500     2.3   2.2
          2200     4.5   0.5
          3100     4.4   0.9
2019-8-2  1100     2.2   1.2
          1400     2.5   1.3
          2200     0.9   1.6
          3500     1.1   0.1
```

I need to get a third column 'C', that will be a diff() from level=1 (Price) in multiindex:

```
                   A     B      C
Date      Price    
2019-8-1  1000     1.1   0.0    NaN
          1500     2.3   2.2    500
          2200     4.5   0.5    700
          3100     4.4   0.9    900
2019-8-2  1100     2.2   1.2    NaN
          1400     2.5   1.3    300
          2200     0.9   1.6    800
          3500     1.1   0.1   1300
```

I tried to use groupby(level=0), but I can't figure out how then to aply diff() to the multiindex level.

Thanks.

Comment: `df.index.to_frame().groupby(level=0)['Price'].diff()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new `MultiIndex Series` with [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html) and seelct second values of tuples by `str[1]` and then use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
df['C'] = df.index.to_series().str[1].groupby(level=0).diff()
```

Or crete new column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
df['C'] = df.assign(P=df.index.get_level_values(1)).groupby(level=0)['P'].diff()
```

---

```
print (df)
                  A    B       C
Date     Price                  
2019-8-1 1000   1.1  0.0     NaN
         1500   2.3  2.2   500.0
         2200   4.5  0.5   700.0
         3100   4.4  0.9   900.0
2019-8-2 1100   2.2  1.2     NaN
         1400   2.5  1.3   300.0
         2200   0.9  1.6   800.0
         3500   1.1  0.1  1300.0
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.index.to_series())
Date      Price
2019-8-1  1000     (2019-8-1, 1000)
          1500     (2019-8-1, 1500)
          2200     (2019-8-1, 2200)
          3100     (2019-8-1, 3100)
2019-8-2  1100     (2019-8-2, 1100)
          1400     (2019-8-2, 1400)
          2200     (2019-8-2, 2200)
          3500     (2019-8-2, 3500)

print (df.index.to_series().str[1])
Date      Price
2019-8-1  1000     1000
          1500     1500
          2200     2200
          3100     3100
2019-8-2  1100     1100
          1400     1400
          2200     2200
          3500     3500
dtype: int64
```

---

```
print (df.assign(P=df.index.get_level_values(1)))
                  A    B     P
Date     Price                
2019-8-1 1000   1.1  0.0  1000
         1500   2.3  2.2  1500
         2200   4.5  0.5  2200
         3100   4.4  0.9  3100
2019-8-2 1100   2.2  1.2  1100
         1400   2.5  1.3  1400
         2200   0.9  1.6  2200
         3500   1.1  0.1  3500
```

EDIT:

Another solution from [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57462264/apply-diff-to-pandas-multiindex-level/57462298#comment101397935_57462264):

```
df.index.to_frame().groupby(level=0)['Price'].diff()
```

Comment: Thanks for 2 variants with explanation. But I actually like the variant in the comment more. It looks more transparent and simpler. Although from your answer one could learn more.

Comment: @AntonZi - Just see it, added to answer too.